# Flutter issue, ios app won't open and no icon

Tags: ios, xcode, dart, flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tO8XS.jpg)

There's zero error, zero warning in Xcode.

doctor:

> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): [✓]
>   Flutter (Channel master, v1.3.12, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale
>   en-US) [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android
>   SDK version 28.0.3) [✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode
>   10.1) [✓] Android Studio (version 3.3) [✓] Connected device (1 available)
>
> • No issues found!

There's no icon on the app and it won't open
pubspec:- 
    name: ****
    description: A new Flutter application.

```
# The following defines the version and build number for youra application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  device_info: "^0.2.1"
  shared_preferences: "^0.4.2"
  flutter_webview_plugin: "^0.3.0"
  connectivity: "0.4.2"
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.0"
  url_launcher:
  fluttertoast:
  http: ^0.12.0
flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: "Example-Icon"
  image_path: "images/Launcher_92.jpg"
  image_path_android: "images/Launcher_92.jpg"
  image_path_ios: "images/Launcher_92.jpg"

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  assets:
  - images/splash_screen.png
  - images/BG_Login_Flow01.jpg
  - images/BG_Login_Flow02.png
  - images/BG_Login_Flow03.png
  - images/Launcher_92.png
  - images/App_Splash_v1.png
  - images/App_Startup_400px_emojis.gif

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  fonts:
  - family: Poppins
    fonts:
    - asset: fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf
  - family: Roboto
    fonts:
    - asset: fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf


  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

**UPDATE::**

ok so the update is I'm unable to open ipa built by "iOS app store" option but when I built it using "development" option it works fine. Is this is how it suppose to work or it should work with "iOS app store" option also?

Comment: What output do you have when you give the command of "flutter run" from the terminal?

Comment: flutter build ios --release then from Xcode I'd build the archive and then export the ipa and then installed it on the device. Although apps work fine in debug mode.

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same problem.

Comment: Yes, This is not the issue thing is you can't open an ipa build with the "ios app store". If you want to check, try "ad-hoc" and make sure you have the certificate on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

You may need commands

> $ flutter logs

to read response from your iphone.

To add an icon for iOS, you would need some other packages, like "flutter_launcher_icons" or "cupertino_icons".

Take flutter_launcher_icons for example,
you need to add dependancies in your pubspec.yaml,

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons:

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: "BLE4.0"
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  image_path_android: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  image_path_ios: "assets/icon/icon.png"
```

and then update your ios project file manually.

You can also refer [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)

Comment: It has everything, the apps work fine when it is built in debug mode, I've mentioned that